# Java Variable Visibility

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

There is my code

```java
public class Test {
    private static boolean running = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "get running:" + running);
            while (running) {
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "end");
        }, "t1").start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            running = false;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "change running to:" + running);
        }, "t2").start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "get running:" + running);
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "get running:" + running);
        }, "t3").start();
    }
}
```

console output

```sh
t1get running:true
t3get running:true
t2change running to:false
t3get running:false
```

so the thread `t1` is stuck in while loop. And I know if I change `running` to `private static volatile boolean running` can fix this.

I question is `t3` and `t2` are different thread to, why `t3` can get the new value of `running`
but `t1` can't

**EDIT1**

@andrew-tobilko said it may because I call `Thread.sleep` in the loop body, so I change the code of `t3`

```java
        new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "get running:" + running);
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            while ((now-start)<3*1000L*1000L*1000L){
                now = System.nanoTime();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "get running:" + running);
        }, "t3").start();
```

the result still the same

Comment: I noticed the behaviour to change when the `t1` waits also in the loop body: [demo](https://ideone.com/grpCHn). So it probably has something to do that `while(running) {}` will be converted to a `while(true) {}` loop by the JIT compiler, because it has been deemed a hotspot

Comment: @Lino-Votedon'tsayThanks yeah,I have the same conjecture, the JIT may optimize the loop, but how to verify this

Comment: @apangin do you have any advice about this

Comment: There is no happens-before between reads and writes to `running` so partucular JVM implementation you are using can do whatever it wants regarding visibility if that variable in different threads. Some threads may see initial value, some may see new value

Answer (score 6):

When you have a variable which you want to use to communicate between threads, then [mark that variable as volatile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html):

```
private static volatile boolean running = true;
```

The reason is that threads are allowed to cache variables thread-locally for performance reasons or do other performance optimizations which only work on the assumption that the value of a variable won't change in a specific section of code. But the Java compiler and runtime won't be aware that *another* thread might change that variable.

Adding the `volatile` modifier to a variable prevents those optimization and forces the optimizer to assume that this variable can change at any time for any reason.

Comment: as @Lino-Votedon'tsayThanks said ，is it possible that the JIT convert `while(running) {}` to `while(true) {}`?

Comment: @ericzhao Yes, it can. And this is one reason more to make `running` a `volatile` variable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);` in the third thread helps to reload `running` rather than taking it from the cache in registers.

Note that the compiler doesn't have to do so.

> In particular, the compiler does not have to flush writes cached in registers out to shared memory before a call to Thread.sleep or Thread.yield, **nor does the compiler have to reload values cached in registers after a call to Thread.sleep or Thread.yield.**
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3

So it's up to the compiler (and to the optimisations it might do).

> For example, in the following (broken) code fragment, assume that
> this.done is a non-volatile boolean field:
>
> ```
> while (!this.done)
>     Thread.sleep(1000);
> ```
>
> **The compiler is free to read the field this.done just once, and reuse
> the cached value in each execution of the loop.** This would mean that
> the loop would never terminate, even if another thread changed the
> value of this.done.

If you put a `sleep` statement inside the loop in the first thread, it might also get a new value of `running`. Again, no guarantee.

Comment: if I change `t3`
```
new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "get running:" + running);
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            while ((now-start)<3*1000L*1000L*1000L){
                now = System.nanoTime();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "get running:" + running);
        }, "t3").start();
```
I didn't call sleep or yield  and the result is the some

Comment: @ericzhao then it might have been optimised by the runtime compiler, it might have assumed `while (running)` is the same as `while(true)`, which, in fact, is (given that the variable is non-volatile)